# Connecting to service hosted on Compute Engine not working - Site cannot be reached / I have added the http(s) tags

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

Team, Need quick help! I have created and hosted service on Compute engine in GCP. This is on a Ubuntu server, While creating the instance, I have made sure, allow-HTTP && allow-HTTPS flag was enabled. but still, I'm not able to connect to the service from outside.

I have exposed the service on port 4000 but the tcp:80 should be allowing the HTTP traffic to come-in. I'm kinda going in circles without an outcome.

[image: Network details of the instance]

Comment: You do not have a firewall rule allowing TCP port 4000 traffic.

Comment: Either allow TCP traffic on port 4000 as @John Hanley says or expose your service on port 80/443 by means of Nginx/Apache for example.

Comment: "While creating the instance, I have made sure, allow-HTTP && allow-HTTPS flag was enabled." by doing that you've enabled ingress connections to ports 80 and 443. "I have exposed the service on port 4000 but the tcp:80 should be allowing the HTTP traffic to come-in." Your service is running on port 4000 which is closed. You can change port of your service to 80 or configure firewall to allow ingress connections on port 4000.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did add a separate rule to enable port 4000 to get the call flowing to my service, it worked. To be sure and have a safe exposure! I changed the Architecture, added a reverse proxy in front of it, and exposed the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question:

> While creating the instance, I have made
> sure, allow-HTTP && allow-HTTPS flag was enabled.

Accordingly to the documentation [Creating and starting a VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) section [Creating an instance from a public image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage):

> 10. Select **`Allow HTTP traffic`** or **`Allow HTTPS traffic`** to permit HTTP or HTTPS traffic to the VM. When you select one of these, Compute Engine
>     adds a network tag to your VM, which associates the firewall rule with
>     the VM. **Then, Compute Engine creates the corresponding ingress
>     firewall rule that allows all incoming traffic on tcp:80 (HTTP) or
>     tcp:443 (HTTPS).**

as a result, you enabled ingress connections to your instances to ports 80 and 443 and other ports will be closed, except the [ports opened by default rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc).

On the other hand you have an application listening on the port 4000:

> I have exposed the service on port 4000

As a result, you're not able to reach your application via `http://EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE:4000` because you didn't open port 4000 as it was mentioned by *@John Hanley* in the comment.

**There are 2 ways to solve your issue**:

1. Change setting of your application to expose it on port 80
2. Follow the documentation [Using firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) and [create a new firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow ingress traffic to your VM instance on the port 4000 through the Console or [via command line](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#gcloud).